# Format the data accessed from database

Tags: php, javascript

I am new to web design. I have accessed data from a MySQL database using PHP. The data are appearing as list or same as table and I need to know how to format that data to fill the text fields in my webpage.

Is it done by JavaScript?

CODE USED:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Retrieve data from database </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("mysql.myhost.com", "user", "sesame") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("mydatabase") or die(mysql_error());

// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

   // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
  echo $row['FirstName'] . "<br />";

  }

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: format.... how? how do you want them to display?

Comment: do you mean putting it into a input field or actually formatting the data before putting it into a input field? Either echo the field in the `value=""` part of the input, or modify the variable to the way you want it to look then echo it out.

Comment: Did you understand the php code, particularly the `while` and `echo` lines? If you understand that, it should be clear what you can do (I mean clear to you, because from what the question says we can't know how the data looks like, what your text fields are, and how you want it to look like).

Comment: Show us the basic layout you require for your page and someone will get you started.

Comment: I am working on designing a webportal...during search in that site,data should be fetched from database and it need to be displayed in certain format(format in the sense color,style,alignment,grid for each set of data)with images...how shall i do it.....still now have accessed this php file using ajax to main page...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want, but I think you mean to have it in the form ...

`echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Firstname[]\" value=\"".$row['FirstName']."\" >";}`

Comment: I am working on designing a webportal...during search in that site,data should be fetched from database and it need to be displayed in certain format(format in the sense color,style,alignment,grid for each set of data)with images...how shall i do it.....